# How I can manipulate the DirectionsRenderer in google maps

Tags: google-maps, maps

I try to draw a route in google maps from an initial and final point, google gives me a route that I can modify the points of the streets, but if I want to cross a section as a shortcut where the map don't have a street, the map does not recognize it and don't take that route. Exits a way where I can shortcut streets?

I upload the code of what I have and an image of what I try to do.

[Example where I want shorcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwpZr.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Travel modes in directions</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
function initMap() {
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
   draggable: true
  });
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var request = {
  origin: {lat: 37.77, lng: -122.447},  // Haight.
     destination: {lat: 37.768, lng: -122.511},  // Ocean Beach.
  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.BICYCLING,
  unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
 };
 directionsService.route(
  request,
  function(response,status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ');
      }
  }
 );
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     zoom: 14,
     center: {lat: 37.77, lng: -122.447}
   });
   directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
 }

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBwm19SMHtEZaXzloVeyMeMULkciJuatEo&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The posted code doesn't generate the pictured route.

Comment: I just updated the code

Comment: Do you just need the polyline (with the shortcut)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option:  extract the polyline returned by the directions service, extract the points before and after your "detour", connect them with a straight line.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ke782e7n/3/)

[image: image of modified route]

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true,
    suppressBicyclingLayer: true,
    suppressPolylines: true
  });
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var request = {
    origin: {
      lat: 37.77,
      lng: -122.447
    }, // Haight.
    destination: {
      lat: 37.768,
      lng: -122.511
    }, // Ocean Beach.
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.BICYCLING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
  };
  directionsService.route(request,
    function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        renderDirectionsPolylines(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ');
      }
    }
  );
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: {
      lat: 37.77,
      lng: -122.447
    }
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
var polylineOptions = {
  strokeColor: '#039be5',
  strokeOpacity: 0.7,
  strokeWeight: 6
};
var polylines = [];

function renderDirectionsPolylines(response) {
  var detourEnd = new google.maps.LatLng(37.766559, -122.50216);
  var detourStart = new google.maps.LatLng(37.766788, -122.495332);
  for (var i = 0; i < polylines.length; i++) {
    polylines[i].setMap(null);
  }
  var ignorePts = false;
  var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
  for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
    var steps = legs[i].steps;
    for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
      var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
      var stepPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline(polylineOptions);
      for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
        if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(nextSegment[k], detourStart) < 1) {
          ignorePts = true;
        }
        if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(nextSegment[k], detourEnd) < 1) {
          ignorePts = false;
        }
        if (!ignorePts) stepPolyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
      }
      polylines.push(stepPolyline);
      stepPolyline.setMap(map);
      // route click listeners, different one on each step
      google.maps.event.addListener(stepPolyline, 'click', function(evt) {
        infowindow.setContent("you clicked on the route<br>" + evt.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
        infowindow.setPosition(evt.latLng);
        infowindow.open(map);
      })
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```