# Suggest custom direction for google map when not available

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a google map app to show the street direction for multiple given spots. I notice that if any of the spots is a bit special (for example an island) that Google does not know how to get there, it will not show the direction for the entire trip.

I wonder if there is away to feed a custom route, or at least tell Google to draw a straight line when it encounters such spot so that the whole trip direction can be shown somehow?

If that's not possible, I wonder if there is any suggestion to resolve this particular problem.

Comment: There is no API setting that I am aware of to do that.

Comment: related question: [How to make mixed path road type? (snap to roads and simple polyline) Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120708/how-to-make-mixed-path-road-type-snap-to-roads-and-simple-polyline-google-map)

Comment: related question: [How I can manipulate the DirectionsRenderer in google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772581/how-i-can-manipulate-the-directionsrenderer-in-google-maps)